# Как обработать 6! условий?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм

Макет программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код нажатия кнопки "Генерировать пароль":

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    if(CheckBox1->Checked == false && CheckBox2->Checked == false && CheckBox3->Checked == false && CheckBox4->Checked == false && CheckBox5->Checked == false)
            ShowMessage("Вы не выбрали параметры пароля!");
    else
            if(Edit1->Text == "")
                    ShowMessage("Вы не ввели длину пароля!");
            else
                    if(StrToInt(Edit1->Text) > 66)
                            ShowMessage("Максимальная длина пароля \"66\"!");
                    else
                    {
                            char s_russian[] =
                            {
                                    'а','б','в','г','д','е','ё','ж','з','и','й','к','л','м','н','о','п','р','с','т','у','ф','х','ц','ш','щ','ъ','ы','ь','э','ю','я'
                            };
                            char S_RUSSIAN[] =
                            {
                                    'А','Б','В','Г','Д','Е','Ё','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я'
                            };
                            char s_latin[] =
                            {
                                    'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
                            };
                            char S_LATIN[] =
                            {
                                    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
                            };
                            char s_num[] =
                            {
                                    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
                            };
                            char s_esc[] =
                            {
                                    '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','-','=','+','.',',',':',';','"','?'
                            };


                            int password_length = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
                            char password_value[67];
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
static char s_russian[] ="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцшщъыьэюя";
/* ... */
static char s_num[] = "0123456789";
static char s_esc[] = "!@#$%^&*()-=+.,:;\"?";

std::string password_chars = "";

if( use_russian ) {
    password_chars += s_russian;
}    
if( use_russian_upper ) {
    password_chars += S_RUSSIAN;
}
/* ... */
if( use_digits ) {
    password_chars += s_num;
}
if( use_esc ) {
    password_chars += s_esc;
}
```

Comment: Хм, а с текстом даже лучше, чем с массивами

Comment: А обязательно выносить из кавычек символы?

Comment: Во избежании случайных модификаций лучше массивы заменить на `const char*`. От `static` особого профита тогда не будет.

Answer (score 1):

1. По нажатию на кнопку, создаете новый динамический массив `allChars`.
2. Проверяете все флаги, если стоит флаг, добавляете в массив `allChars` соответствующие символы.
3. Теперь у вас есть массив `allChars` со всеми допустимыми символами.
4. В цикле выбираете случайный элемент массива `allChars` (от 0 до N-1).