# Преобразование std::string в AnsiString

Tags: c++, c++builder

```
char s_russian[] =
    {
        'à','á','â','ã','ä','å','¸','æ','ç','è','é','ê','ë','ì','í','î','ï','ð','ñ','ò','ó','ô','õ','ö','ø','ù','ú','û','ü','ý','þ','ÿ'
    };

std::string password_chars = "";
password_chars += s_russian;
Edit2->Text = password_chars;
```

Компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(67): E2034 Cannot convert '_STL::string' to 'AnsiString'

Comment: Русские символы некорректно копируются

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор пишет что он не может `std::string` конвертировать в `AnsiString` (а `Edit2->Text` является именно `AnsiString`-ом).
Сделайте `Edit2->Text = password_chars.c_str()`;

Comment: У меня в конце строки какой то непонятный символ, что это? Вставляю его в строку браузера - пробел.

Comment: Строка char* должна заканчиваться нулевым символом, иначе она будет считаться незаконченной, и в неё может попасть мусор который находится в памяти после символов которые вы инициализировали. В конец массива добавьте символ `'\0'`.

Comment: @А разве он не должен добавляться автоматически?

Comment: А почему он должен добавляться автоматически, если вы задаёте строку массивом? Ведь компилятор не понимает, что вы из этого массива хотите сделать строку.
Вот если бы вы написали `char s_russian[] = "àáâãäå¸æçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ";`, тогда бы компилятор добавил 0 в конце строки автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо вам,  буду знать)

Answer (score 3):

Если есть возможность, лучше вообще не мешать борландские `AnsiString` с `std::string`. А вместо `AnsiString` использовать просто `String`, который будет разворачиваться в `Ansi-` или `Unicode-` в зависимости от настроек проекта.

В данном случае проблему можно решить созданием объекта `AnsiString` с помощью [конструктора](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__AnsiString__AnsiString@char_@unsigned_int.html), который принимает указатель на `char` и кол-во элементов.

```
Edit2->Text = AnsiString(s_russian, sizeof(s_russian));
```

Или заменить исходный массив на строковый литерал:

```
const char* s_russian = "русские_буквы";
Edit2->Text = s_russian;
```

Comment: Согласен, но это уже другой вопрос: стоит или не стоит делать так, как делает автор :-)

Comment: @VladimirPavluk знать как обойти ошибку - хорошо, но ещё лучше - не допускать ситуаций, провоцирующих ошибки :)

Comment: Так не выводит password_chars

Comment: [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(68): E2285 Could not find a match for 'AnsiString::AnsiString(_STL::string,unsigned int)'

Comment: @Евгений а почему у Вас первый аргумент `std::string`, если `s_russian` это массив `char`?

Comment: А как надо? У меня несколько массивов и я их +=

Comment: В password_chars

Comment: Получается надо объявить массив как строковый литерал?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577556/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-6-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @Евгений в вопросе у Вас только один показан, про другие ничего не сказано. `std::string` нормально склеивает через `+=`, так что для перевода в `AnsiString` можете использовать метод Владимира и не париться.